# Changing the font color of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, fonts, colors

So I have tried many of the solutions here on Stackoverflow but I can never figure out how to do it. I'm a bit of a newbie. So I have a ListView and want to change the font. 
Here is my Java class that contains my ListView

```
package qax.khabaralyoum;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.ActionBarPullToRefresh;
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout;
import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.listeners.OnRefreshListener;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainListActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static final int NUMBER_OF_POSTS = 20;
    public static final String TAG = MainListActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    protected JSONObject mBlogData;
    protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            GetBlogPostsTask getBlogPostsTask = new GetBlogPostsTask();
            getBlogPostsTask.execute();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network is unavailable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        //Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_items), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        try {
            JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");
            JSONObject jsonPost = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(position);
            String blogUrl = jsonPost.getString("url");

            Intent intent
                    = new Intent(this, BlogWebViewActivity.class);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(blogUrl));
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            logException(e);
        }
    }

    private void logException(Exception e) {
        logException(e);
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }

        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void handleBlogResponse() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (mBlogData == null) {
            updateDisplayError();

        } else {

            try {
                JSONArray jsonPosts = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> blogPosts =
                        new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonPosts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject post = jsonPosts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = post.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();

                    HashMap<String, String> blogPost = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    blogPost.put(KEY_TITLE, title);

                    blogPosts.add(blogPost);

                }

                String[] keys = {KEY_TITLE};
                int[] ids = {android.R.id.text1};
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, blogPosts, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, keys, ids);
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                logException(e);
            }
        }

    }

    private void updateDisplayError() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.error_title));
        builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.error_message));
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        TextView emptyTextView = (TextView) getListView().getEmptyView();
        emptyTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_items));

    }

    private class GetBlogPostsTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
            int responseCode = -1;
            JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://idoodling.com/api/get_recent_posts/");

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                responseCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }

                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(builder.toString());

                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Unsuccessful HTTP response code: %d", responseCode));
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                logException(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logException(e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logException(e);
            }

            return jsonResponse;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            mBlogData = result;
            handleBlogResponse();
        }

    }

    public void activity2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, qax.khabaralyoum.BlogWebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

I know from the solutions that I need an Adapter of some sort to change the font. I think I have an Adapater in my Class but do I need to edit or add something to it so I can connect it to an XML in order to change the font color? I would love a bit of a step by step guide for me to do it regarding the code that I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your post, you do need to set the font color in your Adapter. To do this, you need to override the default `getView` and change it so that it sets the color of the text for the TextView. To do this, change

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, blogPosts, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, keys, ids);
```

to

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, blogPosts, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, keys, ids){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        return view;

    };
};
```

You will need to change `Color.RED` to the color you want. If you're using a hexadecimal color code, you can do `Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")`, replacing `#FFFFFF` with your color. See the Android documentation page about Color if you need more info about getting a Color object. (The page can be found at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)